# grep pattern in LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: linux, grep

I want to export a folder to LD_LIBRARY_PATH but only once. I tried the following to determine if the folder was already present

```
 if !(grep --quiet "libBigWig/include" $LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
 then
     echo "passed"
 fi
```

but it prints the statement. Here's my LD_LIBRARY_PATH

```
/etc:/etc/lib64:/path-to-lib/libBigWig/include
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
if [ `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH | grep 'libBigWig/include'` = '' ] 
then 
    echo 'Not present..'
fi
```

Would this help?

Comment: If the pattern is not present, it returns `[: ==: unary operator expected`. I used `if [ ! \`echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH | grep "libBigWig/lib"\` ] \n then \n echo "passed" \n else \n echo 'failed' \n fi` instead. `echo`ing the $LD_LIBRARY_PATH is what I was looking for.